# C : the number of parameter in function declaration do not match with function call

Tags: c

Recently , I have been reading the source code of PVFS2.8.2.

function `PINT_req_sched_post` is declared like this:

```
int PINT_req_sched_post(enum PVFS_server_op op,
                        PVFS_fs_id fs_id,
                        PVFS_handle handle,
                        enum PINT_server_req_access_type access_type,
                        enum PINT_server_sched_policy sched_policy,
                        void *in_user_ptr,
                        req_sched_id * out_id);
```

however,in `Request-scheduler-test.c` the function is called like this:

```
 ret = PINT_req_sched_post(&(req_array[0]), 0, NULL, &(id_array[0]));
```

the number of parameters do not match .

and `req_array[0]` is a `struct PVFS_server_req` type,definition is :

```
   struct PVFS_server_req
   {
      enum PVFS_server_op op;
      PVFS_credentials credentials;
      PVFS_hint hints;

       union
      {
         struct PVFS_servreq_create create;
         struct PVFS_servreq_unstuff unstuff;
         struct PVFS_servreq_batch_create batch_create;
         struct PVFS_servreq_remove remove;
         struct PVFS_servreq_batch_remove batch_remove;
         struct PVFS_servreq_io io;
         struct PVFS_servreq_getattr getattr;
         struct PVFS_servreq_setattr setattr;
         struct PVFS_servreq_mkdir mkdir;
         struct PVFS_servreq_readdir readdir;
         struct PVFS_servreq_lookup_path lookup_path;
         struct PVFS_servreq_crdirent crdirent;
         struct PVFS_servreq_rmdirent rmdirent;
         struct PVFS_servreq_chdirent chdirent;
         struct PVFS_servreq_truncate truncate;
         struct PVFS_servreq_flush flush;
         struct PVFS_servreq_mgmt_setparam mgmt_setparam;
         struct PVFS_servreq_statfs statfs;
         struct PVFS_servreq_mgmt_perf_mon mgmt_perf_mon;
         struct PVFS_servreq_mgmt_iterate_handles mgmt_iterate_handles;
         struct PVFS_servreq_mgmt_dspace_info_list mgmt_dspace_info_list;
         struct PVFS_servreq_mgmt_event_mon mgmt_event_mon;
         struct PVFS_servreq_mgmt_remove_object mgmt_remove_object;
         struct PVFS_servreq_mgmt_remove_dirent mgmt_remove_dirent;
         struct PVFS_servreq_mgmt_get_dirdata_handle mgmt_get_dirdata_handle;
         struct PVFS_servreq_geteattr geteattr;
         struct PVFS_servreq_seteattr seteattr;
         struct PVFS_servreq_deleattr deleattr;
         struct PVFS_servreq_listeattr listeattr;
         struct PVFS_servreq_small_io small_io;
         struct PVFS_servreq_listattr listattr;
       } u;
    }
```

Can somebody explain this syntax ?

Comment: [HERE](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~robl/pvfs2/pvfs2-dox/html/request-scheduler_8h.html) you can find the correct prototype.

Comment: *"function PINT_req_sched_post is declared like this..."* --- where?

Comment: @DevSolar I guess OP saw it on [THIS](http://www.pvfs.org/cvs/HEAD-docs/doc/doxygen/html/group__reqsched.html) page

Comment: @LPs: ...your second link matches with both what the OP stated, and the source (declaration in `src/server/request-scheduler/request-scheduler.h`, definition in `src/server/request-scheduler/request-scheduler.c`, and use in `src/io/job/job.c`). At which point I'm just as confused as the OP about the *test code* and your first link apparently using a different argument list. I would suspect some stack layout black magic if the `struct PVFS_server_req` were passed by *value*, but it's passed by pointer... Any explanation?

Comment: @DevSolar I guess you and op are looking to [THIS](http://orangefs.org/trac/orangefs/browser/tags/v.2.8.8/test/server/request-scheduler/request-scheduler-test.c?order=date) that is related to ver 2.8.8 that is 11 years old. In tags 2.9.3 is the same. Probably no-one maintained that test since 2004, where the prototype was as first linked.

Comment: why there are two different kinds of `PINT_req_sched_post`  ?

Comment: @LPs I see... thank you very much .  I was expecting some black magic...   The truth is I am so stupid......